# Setting up Geoprocessing Model with ArcGIS for Utilities CCTV Processor?

Tags: arcgis-10.3, arcgis-water-utilities, cctv

I have tried to find any already available data on this issue but have come up empty handed.

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 and MS SQL Server in a versioned environment, for inspections we are using a third party CCTV inspection software called pipetech.

I am attempting to check out CCTV Processor for ArcGIS Utilities (http://solutions.arcgis.com/utilities/water/help/cctv-processor/) I have downloaded all the data and models from the ESRI page and I have begun to change the parameters to my MS Access CCTV dump, etc...  The cctv software (3rd party) we use for inspections writes its data to a MS Access database. The model from ESRI will access data from this DB and use it to tag pipes and create a NASSCO rating for the section (at least this is what I am assuming)

The model that they prebuilt for the tool is very complicated to say the least and I am having a problem figuring it out, when I change certain things I seem to completely crash the model.

Does anyone have a tutorial or help file that would help explain how the model works and which components of the model need to be changed?

Comment: ArcSDE no longer exists.  What in what RDBMS will your versioned enterprise geodatabase exist?  What does Access have to do with the file or enterprise geodatabase model?  You should probably be talking to Esri about their model.

Comment: We are using MS SQL Server.  Also The cctv software (3rd party) we use for inspections writes its data to a MS Access database.  The model from ESRI will access data from this DB and use it to tag pipes and create a NASSCO rating for the section (at least this is what I am assuming)  Again I am really just looking for some solid documentation on this tool that explains the various parts of the model and parameters that can be changed.

Comment: You should be asking the model publisher for this information.

Comment: Please always edit the question in response to requests for clarification.  It's not fair to those who would answer to have to look through a comment trail for critical details.

Comment: I emailed ESRI this morning so if I hear back from them I will gladly post whatever they say in the email here.

Comment: It might take a few transfers, but I'd just call the main number once Redlands is awake, and ask to speak with someone in Utility vertical marketing.

Comment: The database needs to be a PACP schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CCTV Processor for ArcGIS Utilities does not calculate the NASSCO PCAP codes it simply maps the data to the location.

You have to pick the correct tables within database for it to work as well. Inspections and Conditions I believe.

The tool is extremely picky about how parameters are entered into it. Whatever folder videos are stored in that the folder name cannot have any symbols or spaces in the path such as (“~”, “ ”, “-”) or anything else. Only underscores are safe but also cannot start the folder name with underscore. It's picky about single versus double quotes as well.

For the PCAP codes you either have to buy software that will cost +$30 000 per year or using the PCAP documentation you can figure out the coding system and write SQL queries that could be run on the database in order to get the PCAP code values, then run the ESRI CCTV processor which will carry over the values, can confirm this works.

There is a newer version of the CCTV processor out that fixes alot of problems with the old one however I was unable to get it to work correctly.